# nextProps and this.props have always the same value

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (nextProps.group.data !== this.props.group.data) {
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

the group.data object is comming from

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {

        group: {
            data: state.group.data,
            isFetching: state.group.isFetching,
            error: state.group.error
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using redux module to collect the data...

I know the the nextPros references to this.props and i know a solution will be to use Immutable.js but I couldn't find a good example of using it and I found many complications integrating it, as I have already so many modules without Immutable.

is there any other solution to compare newProps to this.props or a good example how to use Immutable with Redux.

Thanks,
Lucas Franco

Answer (score 4):

This means that the `data` object from the store isn't changing, you need to make sure that you are returning a new object in the reducer, and **never** mutate it. For example:

```js
// reducer for group
reducer (state = initialState, action) {
...
  // when your code is going to update data return a completely new object
  return {...state,
    data: { ...state.data, ...action.newData} 
    // never something like state.data.someProp = action.someProp
  }
...
}
```

I'd need to see more of your code to be more sure, mainly the reducer.
But if the expression `(nextPros.group.data !== this.props.group.data)` is resulting in `true`, it's certain to say that the reference to the `data` object hasn't changed.